# MiniMagick does not save cropped image

Tags: ruby, carrierwave, minimagick

The following piece of code creates 256 copies of my source image instead of splitting it in 256 32x32 images.

```
source = MiniMagick::Image.from_file(PICTURE_ROOT + source_url)
256.times do |pos|
  x = (pos%16) * 32
  y = (pos/16).floor * 32
  source.crop("32x32+#{x}+#{y}+repage")
  source.write("temp/test_#{x}_#{y}.gif")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: actually minimagick was saving the file correctly. The problem was that the 256 tiles where saved inside a single image.

see this for reference:

http://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile